# Access set value of 2 combo boxes to last Saturday and last Sunday

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to create a button that sets controls on a form [start_date] and [end_date]. I would like [start_date] = last week Sunday | and [end_date] = last week Saturday. I know VBA and macros, but i can't figure the logic on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Gustav. It worked. I made a small functional change to make it do what I wanted it to do.

```
 Private Sub Command_SetWeekClosures_Click()
 Me![StartingDate_TextBox].Value = DatePrevWeekday(Date - 7, vbSunday)
 Me![EndingDate_TextBox].Value = DatePrevWeekday(Date, vbSaturday)
 End Sub
```

Now with you given function as a part of a module,

```
  Public Function DatePrevWeekday( _
  ByVal datDate As Date, _
  Optional ByVal bytWeekday As VbDayOfWeek = vbMonday) _
  As Date

 ' Returns the date of the previous weekday, as spelled in vbXxxxday, prior      to datDate.
 ' 2000-09-06. Cactus Data ApS.

   ' No special error handling.
   On Error Resume Next

   DatePrevWeekday = DateAdd("d", 1 - Weekday(datDate, bytWeekday), datDate)

  End Function
```

That button sets up my text boxes exactly to the date range of last week.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this generic function:

```
Public Function DatePrevWeekday( _
  ByVal datDate As Date, _
  Optional ByVal bytWeekday As VbDayOfWeek = vbMonday) _
  As Date

' Returns the date of the previous weekday, as spelled in vbXxxxday, prior to datDate.
' 2000-09-06. Cactus Data ApS.

  ' No special error handling.
  On Error Resume Next

  DatePrevWeekday = DateAdd("d", 1 - Weekday(datDate, bytWeekday), datDate)

End Function
```

Like this:

```
Command268_Click() 
    Me![start_date].Value = DatePrevWeekday(Date, vbSunday)
    Me![end_date].Value = DatePrevWeekday(Date, vbSaturday)
End Sub
```

Comment: I am having trouble getting the function to integrate with my system. I need it to do the following:                                                                                                 Private Sub Command268_Click()
me.[start_date] = LastWeekSunday                                                     me.[end_date] = LastWeekSaturday
End Sub